# Relationship bettwen route flags using route versus route flags using cat /proc/net/route

Tags: route

When you enter route in the command line, for flags it prints out U, UG, etc.  In the file for route it stores flags as a number 0001, 0003 etc.  How are the numbers for flags in the file /proc/net/route converted to the letters for flags that are printed out using route?

Answer (score 3):

Net-tools sources are [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/net-tools/code/ci/master/tree/).
Decoding flags in lib/inet_gr.c:

```
    /* Decode the flags. */
    flags[0] = '\0';
    if (iflags & RTF_UP)
        strcat(flags, "U");
    if (iflags & RTF_GATEWAY)
        strcat(flags, "G");
    ...
```

And flags are defined in lib/net-support.h. Example:

```
    #define RTF_UP          0x0001          /* route usable                 */
    #define RTF_GATEWAY     0x0002          /* destination is a gateway     */
    #define RTF_HOST        0x0004          /* host entry (net otherwise)   */
```

Comment: For reference these flags are listed in the user space API of the kernel [`include/uapi/linux/route.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.19/include/uapi/linux/route.h#L51-L61).